# EmptyResultDataAccessException as runtime exception

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-jdbc

this is going long in my mind, i still wonder why spring jdbc made `EmptyResultDataAccessException` as runtime exception instead of forcing calling method (by making Exception) to catch a EmptyResultDataAccessException, i personally faced an issue , when i first implement spring jdbc, let us take this first scenario

```
public List<User> getUsers(String firstName){
JdbcTemplate jd = this.getJdbcTemplate();

        List<User> userLst =  jd.query("select query for user here matched firstname", BeanPropertyRowmapper(User.class))
}
```

in the above scenario even if this select query doesnt return any value, spring jdbc still creates new List object of type user and returns list object with size 0. so here spring jdbc is not throwing EmptyResultDataAccessException , instead it is creating new List object if there is no rec fetched from DB.

secondly, in case for querying for an object, it behaves differently.

```
User user = jd.queryForObject("select * from user where user_id = [EDITuser id here", User.class)
```

here spring jdbc throws EmptyResultDataAccessException incase it didnt find any record for ***user_id = 1***.

more over, since EmptyResultDataAccessException is runtime exception, i was not forced to catch this exception and do some action for this exception, so most of time developer puzzled and it go unnoticed.

as i said in the first scenario , when i first coded, i was expecting userLst object as null, but actually spring jdbc creates new object which we didnt handle it.

posting this to make myself clear on this aspect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is most probably no way to make everyone happy. Take the contrary, you perfectly know that the row exists because it's a valid ID. Yet, calling this method forces you to catch this exception that will never be thrown so you have an empty catch block, which is bad.

This goes back to the use of runtime exception vs. checked exception, there are plenty of references on this site and elsewhere.

Comment: i disagree with you, i have just give an example, but almost all my select queries are tend to catch emptyresult exception and return null or do some other action, more over  emptyresultdata exception will be swallowed by dataaccessexception, so you never know there is empty row or row exists.

Comment: I guess what you're saying is that you would have preferred the template to return `null` when no row is found instead of throwing an exception. The problem is that you can have a row but that row once mapped can map to null (because the existing row contains null values). There wouldn't be any way for you to differentiate those cases. If you are not concerned by this use case, you should have *one* method that offers that service, catching the exception and returning `null` in this case. But spring, as a multi-purpose framework can't take that choice.